# define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 1 extra part ceasercipher function

Tags: racket

I am currently writing a drracket function for rscipher-3 that consumes a non-empty string s consisting of only alphabet uppercase letters and produces a new string (i.e., ciphertext) with the "right shift of 3" rule applied on s. Here is my function but I keep getting the "define: expected only one expression for the function body, but found 1 extra part" error.

```
(define (rscipher-3 s)
  (define (helper s)
    (cond [(empty? s) '()]
          [(= (first s) "X") (cons "A" (helper (rest s)))]
          [(= (first s) "Y") (cons "B" (helper (rest s)))]
          [(= (first s) "Z") (cons "C" (helper (rest s)))]
          [else (cons (integer->char (+ (char->integer (first s)) 3))
                      (helper (rest s)))]))
   (list->string (helper (string->list s))))
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Sounds like you are using a different language than `#lang racket` that does not allow internal define.  Your 3 cases for X-Z won't work. It should be `[(char=? (first s) #\X) (cons #\A (helper (rest s)))]`. The reason is that `"X"` is a string and not a characters and `string->list` makes a list of characters. `=` is only for comparing numbers. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Some DrRacket dialects/ teaching languages (Beginning Student, Intermediate Student and so on) don't allow definitions with multiple expressions.

Your `rscipher-3` has two expressions:

First one:

```
(define (helper s)
    (cond [(empty? s) '()]
          [(= (first s) "X") (cons "A" (helper (rest s)))]
          [(= (first s) "Y") (cons "B" (helper (rest s)))]
          [(= (first s) "Z") (cons "C" (helper (rest s)))]
          [else (cons (integer->char (+ (char->integer (first s)) 3))
                      (helper (rest s)))]))
```

Second one:

```
(list->string (helper (string->list s)))
```

You have to change your language- or, if you have to use it, move the definition of the helper function outside `rscipher-3` definition. Also, you don't need these three branches (as noted in the comments, they also don't work, because you should compare with character, not with string):

```
[(= (first s) "X") (cons "A" (helper (rest s)))]
[(= (first s) "Y") (cons "B" (helper (rest s)))]
[(= (first s) "Z") (cons "C" (helper (rest s)))]
```

When you remove them, you can simplify your `cond` to `if`:

```
(define (helper s)
  (if (empty? s) '()
      (cons (integer->char (+ (char->integer (first s)) 3))
            (helper (rest s)))))

(define (rscipher-3 s)
  (list->string (helper (string->list s))))
```

Example:

```
> (rscipher-3 "FOOBAR")
"IRREDU"
```

If your DrRacket language supports [`map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29), you can also do:

```
(define (rscipher-3 s)
  (list->string
   (map (lambda (c) (integer->char (+ (char->integer c) 3)))
        (string->list s))))
```